# Place part of form-group in different column using Bootstrap Grid

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

I want to place the search button in the column next to the input form using the Bootstrap grid, but since both the "input" tag and "button" tag must be in the div with the "form-group" attribute, this makes things difficult.

This is my original code:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 formMove">
                <form id="getposts_form" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control searchBar" id="search" name="search" placeholder="">
                        <button class="btn btn-default searchBtn" type="submit" id="submit ">Search <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                        <br><div id="errors"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div><!--end row-->
```

And this is my failed attempt with nested columns:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 formMove">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <form id="getposts_form" role="form">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control searchBar" id="search" name="search" placeholder="">
                    </div> <!--I want this closing tag to close "col-md-10", but its closing the "form-group"-->
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                <button class="btn btn-default searchBtn" type="submit" id="submit ">Search <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                                <br><div id="errors"></div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not understand why do you need button and input within the same `form-group class`, as you can use separate form-group class for them.
The approach through which in line forms are achieved is using  `.form-inline` class with the`<form>` tag. As you wanted an answer using grid system I have provide a snippet for that also.

I have added two snippet

**using .form-inline class**

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      
       <style type="text/css">
      
       </style>
       <script type="text/javascript">
        
       </script>
       </head>
       <body>
       
     

<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 formMove">
                <form id="getposts_form" class="form-inline" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control searchBar" id="search" name="search" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-default searchBtn" type="submit" id="submit ">Search <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></div>
                        <br><div id="errors"></div>
                   
                </form>
            </div>
        </div><!--end row-->
</body>
</html>
```

**using bootstrap grid system**

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      
       <style type="text/css">
      
       </style>
       <script type="text/javascript">
        
       </script>
       </head>
       <body>
       
     

<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 formMove">
                <form id="getposts_form" class="form-inline" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8"> 
                        <input type="text" class="form-control searchBar" id="search" name="search" placeholder="">
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"> 
                        <button class="btn btn-default searchBtn" type="submit" id="submit ">Search <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></div>
                        </div>
                        <br><div id="errors"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div><!--end row-->
</body>
```

Comment: Wow. I never would've thought of that. Thanks!